# Where can one find old HP TWAIN drivers?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, scanner

This is really strange...

I have developped a little something for an aplication that uses a scanner with flatbed and optional autofeeder (scan multiples leaves at once ).

I had some troubles, but everything was ok if with my test scanner HP Scanjet5590 I selected the source **hp scanjet 5590 TWAIN 1.0 (32-32)**. The other drivers, namely the most recent ones were really bogus (stretched or partial scans, or unable to manage the auto-feeders, or even completely ineffective).

As I work on multiple other subjects, I dis-installed all HP drivers from my developement machine when my unit tests were done okay.

Now, weeks later, I am just COMPLETELY UNABLE to find that precise version of the driver. In the HP repository, and all over the net all I have found are: the hp scanjet 5590 TWAIN **1.9** (32-32), and other Hp varying Scanjet drivers stuffs with different name but containing 5590... **but all are not working properly**.

So my aim is to find the **hp scanjet 5590 TWAIN 1.0 (32-32)** again.

What would you do in my case ? Where would you search ?

Comment: Have you tried going to HP's official web site? There are a number of vintage drivers listed there. Maybe you will find what you need amongt them. There is also a "contact us" link where you might be able to ask someone at HP for help directly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using archive.org's wayback machine and see if you can find the old drivers from there.